# Field number formatting lost when exporting features

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I am attempting to share a feature layer I created with my organization on ArcGIS Online, and when someone else imported it from the portal all the fields I had specified as being percentages had reverted to numbers. So I:

1. Ensured all of the formatting was correct and again used Share As A Web Layer. When I added it back to my project the formatting was lost.
2. I also used Export Features to add it to my project's local database. Again, when adding it back to the map the formatting was lost.

I made my layer public so I can share it [here](https://services.arcgis.com/WLhB60Nqwp4NnHz3/arcgis/rest/services/ACS_2022_GEOG_402_502/FeatureServer), in case that would be helpful to anyone. I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.